# mySQL - Limit the number of rows returned in one side of JOIN statement?

Tags: mysql

Everyone,

I am just curious if there is a way to do this sort of limiting with a query on a mySQL database:

Here are my tables:

```
Events
   event_id   event_title   creation_time

Images
   image_id   src   event_id

Comments
   event_comment_id   event_comment   event_id
```

I would like to fetch events sorted by creation time, and get only 3 images and 3 comments for each event.

Any help, resources, or criticism is welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach.  Basically, get the rownumber associated with each group of comments/images and only display up to 3:

```
SELECT E.*, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN I.rn = 1 THEN I.Image_Id END) Image1, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN I.rn = 2 THEN I.Image_Id END) Image2, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN I.rn = 3 THEN I.Image_Id END) Image3, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN C.rn = 1 THEN C.event_comment_id END) Comment1, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN C.rn = 2 THEN C.event_comment_id END) Comment2, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN C.rn = 3 THEN C.event_comment_id END) Comment3
FROM Events E
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT @curRow:=IF(@prevRow = event_id, @curRow + 1, 1) rn,
           Image_Id, src, event_id, @prevRow:= event_id
         FROM Images
           JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
         ) I ON E.event_id = I.Event_id
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT @curRow2:=IF(@prevRow2 = event_id, @curRow2 + 1, 1) rn,
           event_comment_id, event_comment, event_id, @prevRow2:= event_id
         FROM Comments
           JOIN    (SELECT @curRow2 := 0) r
         ) C ON E.event_id = C.Event_id 
GROUP BY E.Event_Id
ORDER BY E.Event_Id, E.creation_time DESC
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98a6c/2).